# How to make sure EF would never delete database once forever Not even by mistake

Tags: entity-framework

I learned that EF code first approach deletes database when called with some specific database initialization. It scares crows out of me...

I want to 100% sure it would never delete my database, unfortunately I am not sure what really is going on DB side so I could make sure it's not doable (maybe DB Admin has controls in place).

Even though there are backups and all that sort of things, but as a DEVELOPER I want to be sure what I am developing and deploying won't cause any issue.

Comment: There are ways to avoid this in many levels. But I think the core issue here is permissions. After all, EF would need a connection-string with appropriate credentials to delete a database. So, make sure no developer has "delete database" credentials.

Comment: @haim770 environment we are running code in has service accounts with execute SP permissions only, but developers do have delete DB as they are in sysadmin group for some reasons, am just afraid of having chain of mistakes scenario and then lots of regrets